# Disabling target="_blank" in iframe from opening new window? (or possible work arounds)?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an issue-

I'm creating an html 5 app and including external websites in with an iframe. Inside the external website some of the links have

```
target="blank"
```

When clicked, this exits out of my app and opens up and entirely new window. Ideally, I want to keep them inside the iframe which allows them to use my app navigation (and is the point of an app).

Unfortunately I don't think I'm going to be able to achieve this with frontend technology alone. I'm looking for ANY solution. What I need is to basically get the "iframe" to act as its own window and my nav to be an entirely separate piece.

My current code base is html5, css, javascript, php (but possibly looking into integrating in node.js).

Here is a fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zmx9e/

Comment: iframeing a site that does not want you to is a BAD idea

Comment: It's for them, though the developers were not thinking about that at the time.

Comment: well if you work for Allstate, remove them from source

Comment: I'm a contractor making an app