# Chrome App Login Inside The App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I followed [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) to implement OAuth2 Sign in flow for my app. Everything works great, except that it opens a browser tab and then a popup to log the user in. More specifically, it opens a new tab in Chrome for the user to fill in his email and password, and opens another popup to ask for permissions.

Is there a way to have the sign in form open inside the app?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach to disable chrome from opening up new window and tabs is to build an extension that injects a content script which would parse the DOM and set all `target` attributes of anchor elements to `_self` in every page as suggested in [How to disable chrome from opening up “new window” and “tabs”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606225/how-to-disable-chrome-from-opening-up-new-window-and-tabs).

And to have Google Sign-in form inside the app, you need to integrate Google Sign-In into your app. Given below are steps on how to integrate Google Sign-In into your app:

1. You must have a Google Developers Console project before you can integrate Google sign-in into your website. In the project, you create a client ID, which you need to call the sign-in API.
2. Include the Google Platform Library on your web pages that integrate Google Sign-In.

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>`

3. Specify the client ID you created for your app in the Google Developers Console with the google-signin-client_id meta element.

`<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">`

4. Add a Google Sign-in button

You can explore the links given in [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#top_of_page) for more information on how to properly add and integrate Google Sign-in into your app.